# click anywhere on a table row and it will check the checkbox its in...?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, but I can't find it out. Basically I want to be able to click anywhere on a table row and it will check/ unchecked  the checkbox its in. I know it's possible because that's what PHPMyAdmin does...

here is my table row

```
<tbody>
<tr id="1" onclick="selectRow(1)"><td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="1/"></td><td>1</td><td>2011-04-21 22:04:56</td><td>action</td></tr>

<tr id="2" onclick="selectRow(2)"><td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" id="2" name="2/"></td><td>2</td><td>2011-04-21 22:04:56</td><td>action</td></tr>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectRow(row)
{
    var firstInput = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;
}
</script>
```

...

```
<tbody>
    <tr onclick="selectRow(this)"><td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1/"></td><td>1</td><td>2011-04-21 22:04:56</td><td>action</td></tr>    
    <tr onclick="selectRow(this)"><td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2/"></td><td>2</td><td>2011-04-21 22:04:56</td><td>action</td></tr>  
</tbody>
```

<sub>Note: You've also got collisions on ids. Your ids should be unique.</sub>

Here's an alternative with programmatic binding:

```js
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
  // discard direct clicks on input elements
  if (target.nodeName === "INPUT") return;
  // get the nearest tr
  const tr = target.closest("tr");
  if (tr) {
    // if it exists, get the first checkbox
    const checkbox = tr.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
    if (checkbox) {
      // if it exists, toggle the checked property
      checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk1" />
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2011-04-21 22:04:56</td>
      <td>action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2" />
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2011-04-21 22:04:56</td>
      <td>action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk3" />
      </td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2011-04-21 25:30:16</td>
      <td>action</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: just a note though about using this, is that your checkbox must always be the first input in the table row.

Comment: ...and note that this will only set to "true"; you'll want to add some logic to ensure that it will turn to "false" if necessary, see my answer below.

Comment: @saint Your edit is unnecessary, `firstInput.checked = !firstInput.checked;` already inverts the checked state of the checkbox, but does so in one line instead of your edit which uses ten.

Comment: @canon when i click on the checkbox directly it doesnt change its state. Any advice how to fix this?

Comment: how to check false another row when click one row? i need to check one row at a time, if im checked another row old one went to false, how to do it in this code?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need JavaScript for this:

```css
td label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<td width="20px"><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk2/"></td><td><label for="chk2">2</label></td><td><label for="chk2">2011-04-21 22:04:56</label></td><td><label for="chk2">action</label></td>
```

Just labels and a little CSS.

Comment: Hi - Why do we need td display block ? And can we just apply label to the table row ? Overall great solution

Comment: By default a label is just an inline element, which means it is just the size of  the text it contains. Making it a block element increases the size of the clickable area to the whole table cell.

Comment: And no, you can't just wrap the label around the row, this will create invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  For me, javascript is always a measure of last resort.  I personally wrap all my Checkbox's inside a Label with the display set to block, though this does increase the size (in bytes) of my page holding the Table, so I am warming up to your approach, I just want to future-proof my work, on the off-chance that someday a new table I build will not render oddly because I forgot all the Labels have this CSS attached.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one out...

```
$("tr").click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dVay8/

Comment: jQuery (1.6+):

$("tr").click(function() {
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop('checked'));
});

Answer (score 1):

Since this question getting so many views and the accepted answer has a small issue.

The issue is when you click on the checkbox it won't change. Actually what happens is the checkbox toggles twice. Because of we clicked on the checkbox and the table row as well. So here is a proper solution with a fix.

```
$('tr').click(function(event){
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if(!$target.is('input:checkbox'))
    {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
            if(this.checked) this.checked = false;
            else this.checked = true;
        })
    }
});
```

Good luck devs.